# Make button active after clicking other button

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `button2` is disabled and when someone will click on `Button1`, `Button2` will get activated.

Here is some code I am thinking to use:

```
function fn2() {
    c >= 1 ? alert("Bla Bla") & window.open("login.php", "_self") : window.alert("Please Click")
}
```

I am completely new to JavaScript.

Comment: The code you posted seemingly has nothing to do with either clicking or activating buttons. You're probably looking for something like: `document.querySelector('yourButton1Reference').addEventListener('click', function ( event ) {document.querySelector('yourButton2Reference').disabled = false;});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do it. I am asuming that the buttons have the ids `button1` and `button2`.

```
//When button1 is clicked...
$('#button1').click(function() {
     //Set the property disabled on button2 to false.
     $('#button2').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

And, as usual, make sure that this code isn't executed until the DOM is ready (for instance by wrapping it in `$(function() { ... });`).

Comment: You should not include jQuery like that on JSFiddle. Use the menu to the left. And it seems like you used a very very old version of jQuery that might not support this solution. That is probably not a good idea. But if you want a solution for that version, you should clearly state so in your question. Working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/7q3ajdmw/2/